# Inserted BIGINT is not the same as the one Shown in SQL DataBase

Tags: javascript, mysql, discord.js

I am writing a Discord bot and Twitch bot.
I am currently writing a function to save the users Twitch and Discord ID's in a database.

This is my current function:

```
add_discord(twitch_id, discord_id) {
    this.get_user(twitch_id)
        .then((user_data) => {
            this.db.query(`UPDATE userdata SET discord_id = ${discord_id} WHERE identity_id = ${user_data[0]}`)
        })
}
```

I am using an `identity_id` unique for each user.
I have console logged `discord_id` and it is my correct Discord ID. But once it is put into the database, the number changes.

My discord ID is 522855210926735422

But the number shown in the database is 522855210926735400

(22 off the correct value)

I am using BIGINT's for `discord_id`. I have had a similar issue before, and I previously fixed it (I think) by just storing it as a VARCHAR rather than BIGINT.

Any advice would be great!

(This is the response from the query)

```
OkPacket {
  fieldCount: 0,
  affectedRows: 1,
  insertId: 0,
  serverStatus: 2,
  warningCount: 0,
  message: '(Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0',
  protocol41: true,
  changedRows: 0
}
```

Comment: I don't have the answer for you sadly, but is there a way you can print the database query at the point of execution? So maybe in the ORM or whatever it is you're using; could be in node_modules

Comment: Discord ID values are too big to treat as numbers in JavaScript.

Comment: I have been comparing the inputed values to the ones in the database, and I cant see any correlation

Comment: Pointy, what is the maximum values JavaScript can handle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the `discord_id` is too big for JavaScript. So JS rounds the last to digits (hence ending in 00). So I think I will just make discord_id a string in the database